# When to use [Obsolete] or simply delete the code?

Tags: c#

I am curious when there is a correct time to use the attribute [Obsolete] and the time to just delete the code. Is this something that should be considered in certain patterns like Factory vs Builder? Thanks!

Comment: If it's part of a public api, deleting it might make your users unhappy, since it will break existing code.

Comment: Generally, you use ObsoleteAttribute when you want to maintain a public API for backwards compatibility but you want to discourage future use. The attribute should direct the user to the preferred API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on Programmers.se since it's about a general approach to API design and not a specific programming issue. Duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143622/what-are-the-best-practices-for-phasing-out-obsolete-code

Comment: @JeroenVannevel when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use it in situations where there is code that is not under your control that consumes your class and you want to make a public API change and discourage or block future usage of the old API method/property without breaking binary compatability.

Comment: Is it safe to say that when I Invoke a method from another assembly that I will receive information pertaining to a deprecated method?

Comment: @NicholasKinney Not when you run it.  It's used in the Visual Studio environment — shows up in the Error List window.

Comment: If you compile Assembly `Y` against v1 of assembly `Z` and use method `Foo()`, then in v2 of assembly `Z` you mark `Foo()` as `[Obsolete("Use Bar() instead.", true)]`, if you just drop v2 of `Z` in to the folder with a compiled `Y` nothing bad will happen. However if you reference the v2 of `Z` in your project and try to re-compile `Y` you will get a compile time error preventing you from using `Foo()`.